# use 1 class which exists in 2 references

Tags: c#, .net, types

In .NEt C# How can I tell the compiler to use a Type from a particular class when a second Type exists with the same name in my project references?

A class I wish to use exists in 2 project references.
The namespace etc is identical.
I require both references in the project, but for this particular class I wish to use the one from one of the references assemblies.

Comment: why are both namespaces the same? that sounds "fishy" to me.

Comment: It _is_ fishy. The best solution here would be to avoid it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use [extern aliases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173212.aspx). Anson Horton has a [walkthrough here](http://blogs.msdn.com/ansonh/archive/2006/09/27/774692.aspx).

It's a solution to a problem which you should avoid if at all possible, of course - but it does work.

Ironically enough, I've just been editing the section about extern aliases for the second edition of C# in Depth. Here's the same code, where both First.dll and Second.dll expose a type called "Demo.Example".

```
// Compile with
// csc Test.cs /r:FirstAlias=First.dll /r:SecondAlias=Second.dll

extern alias FirstAlias;
extern alias SecondAlias;

using System;
using FD = FirstAlias::Demo;
class Test
{
   static void Main()
   {
      Console.WriteLine(typeof(FD.Example)); 
      Console.WriteLine(typeof(SecondAlias::Demo.Example));
   }
}
```

Comment: You're faster than your shadow! I was about to write something such as what you have linked. Hehehe... =)

Comment: I'll give it a blast, I came across similar code somewhere, the additional compile args were putting me off.
The assemblies are Microsoft's so I cannot change.

Cheers.